# How to store multiple values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I store multiples values in a dictionary?

Comment: Use `Name` as the key in `stud_data`.

Comment: @Wups that will only work if it is guaranteed that the names are unique (which is not  in a real world application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary that stores records of students, even if they have the same name:

```
stud_data = {}

while True:
    Name = input("Enter the student name :")
    Age = input("Enter the age :")
    Gender = input("Enter the  grade :")
    repeat = input("Do you want to add input more?: ")

    if not Name in stud_data:
        stud_data[Name] = []

    stud_data[Name].append({
        "Name": Name,
        "Age": Age,
        "Gender": Gender
    })

    if repeat == "no" or repeat == "NO":
        break
```

Querying the dict:

```
name = input("Enter student name: ")

print(stud_data.get(name, "Record is not in the dictionary"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Kim mentioned they are supposed to do lookups of students in the final step. One could search the list but I believe a dict is the better choice. I'd suggest:

```
stud_data = {}
while True:
    name = input("Enter the student name :")
    age = input("Enter the age :")
    gender = input("Enter the {} grade :")
    repeat = input("Do you want to add input more?: ")
    stud_data[name] = {'age': age, 'gender': gender}
    if repeat.lower() == "no":
        break


searched_name = input("Enter name to lookup :")
print(searched_name,stud_data.get(searched_name,"Record is not in the dictionary"))
```

Of course Kim will want to clean up the final print.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Yes, there's no attempt to intelligently handle collisions here. However, this is a beginners question. I feel there's no need to add that level of complexity at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you expect `stud_data` to be a list of dictionaries and not a dictionary, so make it a list and use `.append` instead of `.update`.

Also:

- You will need to shift things around if you actually indent to allow the user input multiple times.
- You don't need `flag`. Use `while True` and `break` when needed
- No need for parentheses around a single value

```
stud_data = []
while True:
    Name = input("Enter the student name :")
    Age = input("Enter the age :")
    Gender = input("Enter the {} grade :")
    repeat = input("Do you want to add input more?: ")
    stud_data.append({
        "Name": Name,
        "Age": Age,
        "Gender": Gender
    })
    if repeat == "no" or repeat == "NO":
        break

print(stud_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

As it's said above, you could use a dictionary of lists.
But instead of the break statement I would use the same "repeat" variable.

```
`stud_data = {"Name": [],
             "Age": [],
             "Gender": []}

repeat = 'yes'
while repeat == "yes" or repeat == "YES":
    print(repr(repeat))
    Name = input("Enter the student name :")
    Age = input("Enter the age :")
    Gender = input("Enter the {} grade :")
    repeat = input("Do you want to add input more?: ")

    stud_data['Name'].append(Name)
    stud_data['Age'].append(Age)
    stud_data['Gender'].append(Gender)

print(stud_data)`
```